# filter geojson by date

Tags: node.js, geojson

Is it possible to filter GeoJson data by date, now I only save the position in Mongoose. But I want to make some filters like, show position the last day, the last week, the last month and random dates.

From the documentation of GeoJson I read that date is not possible to add. So any one had done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does it say in the specifications that that's not possible? According to the specification a GeoJSON feature object must have a `properties` member which should be an object (or null):

> A feature object must have a member with the name "properties". The value of the properties member is an object (any JSON object or a JSON null value).

http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects

That object can be used to store data relevant to that specific feature. For example:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "myProperty": "myValue"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [0, 0]
    }
}
```

In that property object you can store the date(s) you need to work with:

```
new Schema({
    'type': {
        type: String,
        default: 'Feature'
    },
    properties: {
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    },
    geometry: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Point'
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer iH8 helps me a lot.